OSGi Service ClassCastException with JUnit and Maven Surefire
In the demo-api-interface module, I have an interface called DemoInterfacePrinter:
public interface DemoInterfacePrinter {
    void printVersion();
}

In the demo-api module, I have the actual implementation of the DemoInterfacePrinter and a OSGi activator:
public class OsgiActivator implements BundleActivator {
    public void start(BundleContext context) {
        try {
            Log.writeToFile("Registering service.");
            DemoInterfacePrinter service = new DemoInterfacePrinterImpl();
            service.printVersion();
            context.registerService(DemoInterfacePrinter.class.getName(), service, null);
            Log.writeToFile("Service registered successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.writeToFile("Error registering service: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) {
        // Service is automatically unregistered
    }
}

The pom.xml of this demo-api is as below, I packaged it as a bundle:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${pom.name}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>-->
                        <Bundle-Activator>org.example.OsgiActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package>org.example.service</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

And in the thrid module, I have a test that try to test the registered OSGi bundle:
public class ContextTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws BundleException, InterruptedException, InvalidSyntaxException {
        // Load the OSGi framework factory
        FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
        Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put("org.osgi.framework.storage.clean", "onFirstInit");
        // Set the OSGi configuration as needed

        // Create and start the OSGi framework
        Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
        framework.start();

        // Load the bundle
        Bundle bundle = context.installBundle("file:/xxx/demo-api/target/demo-api-1.0.0.jar");
        bundle.start();


        // get the bundle context of the bundle
        BundleContext bundleContext = bundle.getBundleContext();
        // get DemoInterfacePrinter service
        ServiceReference<?> ref = bundleContext.getServiceReference(DemoInterfacePrinter.class.getName());
        DemoInterfacePrinter service = (DemoInterfacePrinter) context.getService(ref);
        service.printVersion();
    }
}

But here I got:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.example.DemoInterfacePrinterImpl cannot be cast to class org.example.service.DemoInterfacePrinter (org.example.DemoInterfacePrinterImpl is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader @4d465b11; org.example.service.DemoInterfacePrinter is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I'm using Maven Surefire to launch the test: mvn test -Dtest=ContextTest.
It seems like the error is because the DemoInterfacePrinter class is loaded by the Surefire through system class loader, while the service is loaded by the OSGi bundle class loader.
But if I want to directly do the class cast in this test with Maven Surefire, how can I do it?
I appreciate any helpful information.
